# Textbox styling in CSS returns full border when left blank and lost focus

Tags: html, css, firefox

After typing some characters in textbox then delete it
and then moving cursor (lost focus), the textbox will have a full red shadowed-border. How to remove that so it will only have red-colored bottom border just like first condition?

**CSS CODE :**

```
[type='text']:invalid{
    padding             : 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    width               : 100px;
    border              : none;
    border-bottom       : 2px solid red;
    transition          : all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition  : all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition     : all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition       : all 0.2s ease;
}

[type='text']:valid {
    padding             : 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    width               : 100px;
    border              : none;
    border-bottom       : 2px solid green;
    transition          : all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition  : all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition     : all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition       : all 0.2s ease;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kazekagesama01/m01sknz8)

**Edit :**

Issue seems to be with mozilla firefox as chrome is working fiine!!

Comment: I dont see a full red shadowed-border after removing text and focus out.

Comment: @RahulDesai : enter text...delete it and then click outside the textbox! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor That is exactly what I did. I entered text, removed it with backspace and clicked outside. The bottom border is green when typed something, otherwise red. I dont see any full 4 sided border.

Comment: Yes, type some text, delete it then click outside the textbox. So what is wrong with my code, guys? I only added two event listener, valid and invalid.

Comment: @RahulDesai : which browser? m on moz...

Comment: @NoobEditor did you face the same problem as I did?

I'm using Mozilla

Comment: works fine on chrome

Comment: @NoobEditor I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Able to replicate the issue in Firefox

Comment: Thanks, guys. It all works now. I was told to use outline : none and box-shadow : none.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
input[type='text']
{
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m01sknz8/1/

Comment: It works on Mozilla, man! But when I tried in Chrome, it shows full blue shadowed-border when textbox is focused. Would you like to try in Chrome? I edited the fiddle to this -> http://jsfiddle.net/kazekagesama01/m01sknz8/2/